# No sevara before completing shas?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, torah-study, brisk

In this shiur http://classic.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/895937/Rabbi_Hershel_Schachter/Derech_HaLimud_and_Shiur_of_the_Rav# at about the 26 minute mark Rav Schachter says "they printed" that Rav Chaim Soloveitchik told his children that they shouldn't give sevaros until they have finished all of shas with Rashi. Does anyone know of the source that is being referenced?

Comment: @MiMahMafshach Sorry, can't listen right now, and I really know nothing about how learning works in a yeshiva. So what do they mean by sevaros--like translations, or like conjectures?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89129/who-has-the-right-to-come-up-with-chiddushei-torah

Comment: The beginning of the above shiur discusses a bit of what is meant by sevara. Indeed, it is hard to give a concise definition, but it is different than translations or conjectures. Roughly, it is a conceptual understanding of halakha. For example, one is only liable for the punishment for eating a forbidden food if the amount is greater than an olive's volume. One possible abstract understanding of this fact is that in halakha eating doesn't simply mean imbibing the food. Halakha distinguishes between nibbling and a substantial human activity of eating.

Comment: @MiMahNafshach are you looking for another source for the same concept (the first answer below by Alex) or another source for the same quote from R Chaim Soloveitchik ?

Comment: Ah sorry I realize now that my post is a bit unclear. I am looking for the source from R' Chaim Soloveitchik that is referenced in the shiur. I will edit now

Comment: @MiMahNafshach Ah, ok. Thanks. What is the difference between that and a chakira?

Comment: In my opinion, these terms don't have scientific level precision and are probably used differently by different people in different contexts. But, to me, a chakirah is really two sevaros. Two ways of abstractly understanding the same halakha -- sevara A and sevara B. This can sometimes be done to clarify one's own position, as in, here are two closely related ways of understand the halakha and I'm suggesting sevara A and not B. Or to suggest that these two understandings are at the root of a halakhic disagreement, as in, Rabbi A has sevara A and Rabbi B has sevara B.

Comment: @MiMahNafshach Thanks so much for your patient and thoughtful answers to my questions.

Comment: No problem! Happy if they were at all helpful

Answer (score 8):

R. Meshulam Dovid Soloveitchik discusses this in his essay on derech halimud. In there he describes his tradition of the correct way to learn, going back to his father (R. Yitzchak Zev Soloveitchik) and his grandfather (R. Chaim Soloveitchik). There are several passages there that allude to the idea, but the one I quote below is probably the closest match.

**שעורי רבנו משולם דוד הלוי דרוש ואגדה עמוד נ**

> וזה המצב היום שכן האופן שבו לומדים כיום אין זה בגדר לימוד כלל מחנכים
>   את הבחורים להתעכב על הדף הראשון ולומר סברות ו'תורות' בלא לדעת כלום פעם
>   למדו עוד ועוד מסכתות וכל בחור טוב ידע כמה סדרים וידעו שבחור על גיל
>   עשרים ושתים אינו צריך לומר סברות וחידושי תורה רק ללמוד הרבה מסכתות עס
>   רש"י תוס' ורמב"ם ולהבין היטב מה מחלוקת רש"י ותוס ומה מח' הרמב"ם
>   והראב"ד ורק אחרי שיודע הרבה גמרות יכול לומר בכל מקום הערות וחידושי
>   תורה אמיתיים משא"כ כשאין יודעים הרבה מסכתות וסוגיות הש"ס השכל עדיין לא
>   טעם טעמה של תורה וכשרוצה לומר סברות מעקם את הגמ' כדי שתתאים לשכלו
>   השבוע אמרתי איזה דין בשיעור וכולם היו בדעה פה אחד שאין הדבר כן עד
>   שפתחתי גמ' והראיתי להם שזו גמ' מפורשת הרי היו יכולים להעביר על כך עשרה
>   ימים להתווכח ולחשוב שהם צודקים כך זה כשאין יודעים הרבה גמרות כאשר
>   לומדים באופן זה התורה היא שטחית כי איך אפשר לעיין כראוי כשחסרים ידיעות
>   מקיפות

---

Another source that seems to attribute this idea to R. Chaim Soloveitchik is a pamphlet by R. Shimon Fuerst on proper methodology of learning. In there he relates that he heard the following story from a great Torah scholar who heard it directly from the Gaon of Brod (one of the characters in the story). Most of the story is in Yiddish so I can't provide a real translation, but I think the punchline is that R. Chaim Solovetichik said that you can't say a pilpul without knowing the entire Talmud with Rashi.

**Tenu Kavod LaTorah ([p. 9](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22633&st=&pgnum=10&hilite=))**

> סיפר לי גדול בתורה אחד ששמע מפי קדשו של הגאון מבראד ז"ל (ולא עד מפי
>   עד) פעם אחת נסע לקבל את פני הגאון רבי חיים ז"ל מבריסק בעבור שדיברו
>   לבתו את בנו רבי וועלוועל ז"ל שנעשה אח"כ גאון הדור הר' וועלוועל היה בעת
>   ההיא בערך בן ט"ז שנים
>
> אמר הגאון רבי חיים להגאון מבראד מיין וועלוועל גידענקט גאנץ ש"ס מיט
>   רש"י הרב מבראד עמד נשתומם ושאל את הגאון רבי חיים רבי חיים וואס איז מיט
>   אייך גישעהן זייט ווענן איז בייא אייך בקיאות אויך א ענין בייא אייך
>   לערנט מען דאך נור בעיון
>
> אמר לו הגאון רבי חיים בראדער רב בייא מיר אויב עמעצער זאגט א פילפול
>   איידער ער גידענקט גאנץ ש"ס מיט רש"י איז דאס בייא מיר א פילפול של הבל

---

This idea was also stated by R. Yaakov Kamenetsky.

**Making of a Godol p. 724:**

> "When R' Shurin related his grandfather's opinion on how much gemara
>   to cover to whoever was his *rebbi* at the time, the latter argued
>   that only the prodigies in Slabodka could maintain such a pace, and
>   that if one had to make a choice between broad knowledge and
>   *lomduth*, the latter took primacy. When R' Shurin transmitted his *rebbi*'s thesis back to his grandfather, he exclaimed angrily, "א סברא אהין א סברא אהער [A (*lomduth*) conjecture hither, a conjecture
>   thither]: how can one say a סברא without knowing gemara?!

(The grandfather is R. Yaakov Kamenetsky.)

---

This idea ultimately goes back to the Talmud.

**[Avodah Zara 19a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=19&format=pdf):**

> ואמר רבא לעולם ילמד אדם תורה ואח"כ יהגה שנאמר בתורת ה' והדר ובתורתו
>   יהגה ואמר רבא לעולם ליגריס איניש ואע"ג דמשכח ואע"ג דלא ידע מאי קאמר
>   שנאמר גרסה נפשי לתאבה גרסה כתיב ולא כתיב טחנה
>
> Raba also said the following: One should always study the Torah first
>   and meditate in it afterwards, as it is said, ‘ . . . the Law of the
>   Lord’, and then, ‘and in his [own] law he meditates.’ This, too, did
>   Raba say: Let one by all means learn, even though he is liable to
>   forget, yea, even if he does not fully understand all the words which
>   he studies, as it is said, My soul breaketh for the longing that it
>   hath unto Thy ordinances at all times. ‘Breaketh’ is what Scripture
>   says, it does not say ‘grindeth’. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nezikin/Avodah_Zarah.pdf))

While this passage doesn't specifically use the term "sevara", just a few lines later the Gemara does use the term "sevara" when discussing how many teachers someone should have:

> והיה כעץ שתול על פלגי מים אמרי דבי ר' ינאי כעץ שתול ולא כעץ נטוע כל
>   הלומד תורה מרב אחד אינו רואה סימן ברכה לעולם אמר להו רב חסדא לרבנן
>   בעינא דאימא לכו מלתא ומסתפינא דשבקיתו לי ואזליתו כל הלומד תורה מרב אחד
>   אינו רואה סימן ברכה לעולם שבקוהו ואזול קמיה דרבא אמר להו הני מילי סברא
>   אבל גמרא מרב אחד עדיף כי היכי דלא דלא ליפלוג לישני
>
> And he shall be like a tree transplanted by streams of water. — Those
>   of the school of R. Jannai said: ‘a tree transplanted,’ not ‘a tree
>   planted’ — [which implies that] whoever learns Torah from one master
>   only will never achieve great success. Said R. Hisda to the Rabbinic
>   students: I have a mind to tell you something, though I fear that you
>   might leave me and go elsewhere: ‘Whoever learns Torah from one master
>   only will never achieve great success.’ They did leave him and went
>   [to sit] before Rabbah, who however explained to them that the maxim
>   only applies to lessons in logical deductions, but as to oral
>   traditions it is better to learn from one master only, so that one is
>   not confused by the variation in the terms used. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nezikin/Avodah_Zarah.pdf))

Rashi there writes:

> סברא. ללמוד חריפות וחידוד הלב לאחר שלמד ושגורה בפיו גירסת התלמוד

This is a clear statement that "sevara" comes after one has covered the Talmudic material.

Comment: You have your hither and thither backward.

Comment: @magicker72 That's how it is in Making of a Godol. I imagine he wrote it that way because in English we usually put "here" before "there". E.g. in English we say "neither here nor there" but in Yiddish "נישט אהין נישט אהער".

Comment: My initial question was unclear. I’ve edited to reflect the fact that I’m trying to track down a source attributing such an idea to Rav Chaim

Comment: @MiMahNafshach I edited my answer to include a possible source attributing it to R. Chaim.

Comment: Thanks! That piece looks interesting. I hope to check it out

Comment: Re. where the idea ultimately goes back to, I’d venture to say it is predicated on ליגמר איניש והדר ליסבר ([Shab. 63a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.63a.15?with=all&lang=bi)).

Comment: @Oliver Indeed there are various Talmudic passages that seem to allude to this concept. אי דייקינן כולא האי לא הוי תנינן (Eruvin 48a); לא כאדם המפולפל ומחודד ובעל סברא ולא למד משניות וברייתות הרבה (Rashi’s explanation of Sanhedrin 42a, which is probably related to סיני vs עוקר הרים in Horayot 14a) etc. If I get a chance later I may edit some more sources into the answer.

Comment: @Alex While those quotes reflect a similar idea I think Shab. 43a stands apart as being more specific re. this nuance. It conveys the notion that before attempting to “give sevaros” or “toros” one should first learn [all the source material = Shas]. The other quotes don’t speak to this nuance. (P.S. I think there’s a typo in your quote from R. MDS: “שבחור **על** גיל עשרים ושתים” read “עד”.)